# Import human from MakeHuman has modifier which has (robe, hair and penis) which should not be there

Tags: modifiers, import, parent, makehuman

Anyone seen this issue before?

I import my character from MakeHuman using the Import Human button. It was all normal.

I was having trouble parenting my rig, so I deleted doubles(Merge vertices 'by distance'), but that did not help.

Next, I read that deleting unnecessary modifiers can help. So I tried that and when I deleted the last modifier, my character had a robe, wig and penis.....wut?

No mater what I change, the issue persists.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have makehuman installed on my machine right now, but the modifier you're showing is the Mask modifier that hides certain vertex groups. You're seeing the "helper" geometry that is supposed to aid in fitting hair and clothes to the MH basemesh.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Do you know if there is anyway to disable this before import?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Here ya go yall

[image]

Comment: That looks right. You can save settings as presets if you load a lot of MHX2 files